# Аномалия с annotate django!

Tags: python, django

Переопределяю `models.query.QuerySet`.

```py
class TransactionQuerySet(models.query.QuerySet): 
    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wallets = []
        wallet_transactions = self.values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount'))
        ...
        ...
```

Получаю:

```py
wallet_transactions = <TransactionQuerySet [{'wallet': 1, 'amount': 666}, {'wallet': 1, 'amount': 1000}, {'wallet': 1, 'amount': 500}, {'wallet': 1, 'amount': 1000}]>
```

Почему не работает агрегация в аннотации???
Если написать прямо там же:

```py
Transaction.objects.all().values('wallet').annotate(amount = Sum('amount'))
```

то все ок и получаю:

```py
<TransactionQuerySet [{'wallet': 1, 'amount': 3166}]>
```

self и Transaction.objects.all() - одно и тоже

```py
<TransactionQuerySet [<Transaction: Transaction: B3>, <Transaction: Transaction: B3>, <Transaction: Transaction: B2>, <Transaction: Transaction: B1>]>
```

Хелп ПЛИЗ!!